# Save coordinates of transformed pasted image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm pasting a randomly generated barcode on a background image.

This barcode has been randomly rotated, skewed, and scaled.

Then, this barcode is randomly placed onto the background image.

I'm trying to find out the coordinates of the actual barcode, ignoring the expanded black mask.

I'm a beginner in matrices and image manipulation so any help, especially in the math, would be appreciated.

This is where I generate the barcode, using pdf417gen library, along with the coordinates of the barcode.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import sys

from pdf417gen import encode, render_image
from PIL import Image

def generate_barcode(self):
    barcode = encode("random text data", columns=5, security_level=5)
    scale = 5
    ratio = 3
    padding = 5

    barcode_image = render_image(barcode, scale=scale, ratio=ratio, padding=padding)
    barcode_coords = np.array([
        [(barcode_image.width - padding) / float(barcode_image.width), (barcode_image.height - padding) / float(barcode_image.height)],
        [padding / float(barcode_image.width), (barcode_image.height - padding) / float(barcode_image.height)],
        [padding / float(barcode_image.width), padding / float(barcode_image.height)],
        [(barcode_image.width - padding) / float(barcode_image.width), padding / float(barcode_image.height)]
    ])

    return (barcode_coords, barcode_image)
```

Once I have the barcode's image and coordinate, I do the following.

1. transform the barcode's image
2. attempt to match the coordinates with the image's transformation
3. paste the image onto a background image
4. then draw a red outline using the coordinates

The red outline should outline the barcode's image.

Here's where I transform the barcode image and paste it to the background image.

```
def composite_images(self, background_image, barcode_coords, barcode_image):
    coords = barcode_coords
    barcode = barcode_image

    # instantiating the transformation variables
    scale = random.randrange(4, 50) / 100.0
    size = int( min(background_image.size) * scale) # background_image.size returns (width, height)
    barcode = barcode.resize((int(size * 2.625), size)) # width:height ratio is 2.625:1
    rotation = random.randrange(0, 360)
    xstretch = random.randrange(0, 100) / 100.0
    ystretch = random.randrange(0, 100) / 100.0
    xshear = random.randrange(0, 100) / 100.0
    yshear = random.randrange(0, 100) / 100.0

    # set affine transform on the barcode coordinates
    affine_transform = get_affine_transform(rotation, xstretch, ystretch, xshear, yshear)
    coords = transform_coords(coords, affine_transform, True)
    expand_mask = transform_coords(np.array([  # shifts expand mask based on transformation
        [0.0, 0.0],
        [float(size * 2.625), 0.0],
        [float(size * 2.625), float(size)],
        [0.0, float(size)]
    ]), mat, False)

    minx = min(expand_mask[:,0])
    maxx = max(expand_mask[:,0])
    miny = min(expand_mask[:,1])
    maxy = max(expand_mask[:,1])

    mat_inv = np.linalg.inv(np.array([  # the inverse matrix
        [mat[0,0], mat[0,1], -minx],
        [mat[1,0], mat[1,1], -miny],
        [0,0,1.0]
    ]))
    image_matrix = (mat_inv[0,0], mat_inv[0,1], mat_inv[0,2], 
        mat_inv[1,0], mat_inv[1,1], mat_inv[1,2])
    new_size = (int(maxx-minx), int(maxy-miny))

    # set affine transform on the barcode image using data from coordinates affine transformation
    barcode = barcode.transform(new_size, method=Image.AFFINE, data=image_matrix)

    # paste the barcode image onto a random position on background image
    region_x = random.randrange(0, background_image.width - size)
    region_y = random.randrange(0, background_image.height - size)
    background_image.paste(barcode, (region_x, region_y))

    coords *= scale
    coords += [region_x / float(background_image.width), region_y / float(background_image.height)]

    return(coords, background_image)

def get_affine_transform(self, rotation, xstretch, ystretch, xshear, yshear):
    theta = -(rotation / 180.0) * np.pi
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(theta) * xstretch, -np.sin(theta) * xshear],
        [np.sin(theta) * ystretch, np.cos(theta) * yshear]
    ])

def transform_coords(self, coords, affine_transform, center):
    if center:
        coords -= (.5, .5) # center on origin
    coords = np.dot(coords, affine_transform.T)
    if center:
        coords += (.5, .5) # reset centering
    return coords
```

Now I draw the red outline using the coords and image (with pasted barcode) returned from `composite_images()`.

```
def draw_red_outline(self, box_coords, image):
    outline = box_coords * [image.width, image.height]
    outline = outline.astype(int)
    outline = tuple(map(tuple, outline))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.poly(outline, outline=(255,0,0,0))
    del draw

    image.show()
```

I'm unsure as to where my math is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get coordinates of transformed points you can do the following:

After getting transformation matrix:

```
transformed_img = cv2.warpPerspective(source_img, m, image_shape)
```

You apply it to image:

```
transformed_img = cv2.warpPerspective(source_img, m, image_shape)
```

and transformed image contains result with coordinates which you want to calculate and some black region.

So, the solution for each of 4 points' coordinates (if there are no 0 coordinates) is the following:

```
point = np.array([w, h]) #width and hight of the source point (before transform)
homg_point = [point[0], point[1], 1] # homogeneous coords
transf_homg_point = m.dot(homg_point) # transform
transf_homg_point /= transf_homg_point1[2] # scale
transf_point = transf_homg_point[:2] # remove Cartesian coords
print(transf_point) #check the result
```

[image: tranformation coordinates]